# Trying to make an Ascii-based game; JFrame doesn't show

Tags: java, swing, jframe, ascii

I have been stuck on this for quite a long time.

So I am using somebody's AsciiPanel library. It is a library that, when the AsciiPanel is added to the JFrame, will create an 80x24 old-style Windows command line with Ascii graphics (for roguelikes, etc.).

I am trying to add the AsciiPanel to the JFrame.

The problem is, I don't think I created the JFrame anywhere. I don't want to add it anywhere weird and make the code unreadable/unconventional for later, so I decided to ask the community here. This is the code:

```
package com.base.engine;


import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import com.base.game.Game;
import asciiPanel.AsciiPanel;


public class Main extends JFrame{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static AsciiPanel asciiPanel;
    private static Game game;
    public boolean gameRunning = true;

    public Main() {
        initDisplay();
        initGame();
        gameLoop();
    }

    private void initDisplay() {
        asciiPanel = new AsciiPanel();
        add(asciiPanel);
        pack();
    }
    private static void initGame() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        game = new Game();
    }
    private void gameLoop() {
        while(gameRunning = true) {
            game.getInput();
            game.update();
            game.redraw();
        }   
    }

    void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        gameRunning = false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main game = new Main();
        game.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I also think the gameLoop() may be what is screwing it up, because I think it worked fine just before I added it.

Thank you for any information.

Comment: Have your tried removing each of the orders you have inside the gameLoop()? or maybe add in a sleep so it will wait for a bit after finishing each part of the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, your game loop is blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing it from processing repaint requests or incoming events.

Depending on your needs, you're better of using a `javax.swing.Timer`, `SwingWorker` or `Thread`.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

The things to remember are, Swing is single threaded framework, this means that all creations and updates of/to all UI components are expected to occur within the context of the EDT.

Equally, any action which blocks the EDT will prevent it from updating the UI (or processing events)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try looking into it.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I still don't get it. Since I am attempting to make a turn-based game, I don't think I'll need timers or frames.

Is there a smarter way to make the code move every time I perform an action?

Comment: By frames I mean the FPS, not the JFrame.

Comment: @BitLion Oh hell yes!  Simply use the available controls and components and react to the events as they occur.  You don't need a "main-loop", Swing already provides one.  How you achieve this will come down to how the user interface works, but [Writing Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/) might help

Comment: Thank you for the link!
I'm in Japan with my family right now and it may be hard to be active, but I'll try out what you suggested. Thank you!
I'll just mark your answer for the links :)

Comment: @BitLion Awesome!  Hope you have a fun and safe trip!